# Generate checkboxes in or selectable buttons in WPF from database

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I am new to C# and need a little bit of help. I want to import a table with three columns from a csv(semicolon separated) database. Then I want to go through all rows of the table, get all the rows with a "value" and then make checkboxes or multi-selectable buttons of some sort appear depending on "value". I am not sure how to do this, so I have just started with trying to import the data from the database. Here is the code I have:

```
class Nettstasjoner
    {
        public string NS { get; set; }

        public string Sek { get; set; }

        public string Radial { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        Value = "H812"; //this will be set from a button later

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> strCSV =
                File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\thomoe\Desktop\SMSvarsel\nsdatabase.csv");
            var results = from str in strCSV
                          let tmp = str.Split(';')

                          select new
                          {
                              NS = tmp[0],
                              Sek = tmp[1],
                              Radial = tmp[2]
                          };

            foreach (var tmp in results)
            {
                //here I need to select all rows with the Value value in it and make a checkbox or something with the captin from the row NS(tmp[0]).
            }
        }
    }
```

I am very open to other ways of doing this, including MVVM, I have just tried to do what I can with googling and so on. Now I am stuck though. Thank you so much for helping and please be very specific when answering ;) My understanding of C# is still very slim :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already have a collection of data.

First, make your collection more "object-like" by explicit class decloration:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string NS { get; set; }
    public string Sek { get; set; }
    public string Radial { get; set; }
}
```

and change your code to

```
select new MyModel
{
    NS = tmp[0],
    Sek = tmp[1],
    Radial = tmp[2]
};
```

Next you need to use one of [item containers](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/) in your view, for example [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx with your custom [template](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) which will show an checkbox and anything else for your model class.

Finally you need to bind your collection from ViewModel to the ListView by using [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

It's not completed solution but I hope it'll help you to understand the main principle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **TextFieldParser**

```
    TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\thomoe\Desktop\SMSvarsel\nsdatabase.csv");
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(";");
    List<MyStruct> myData = new List<MysTruct>();
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        //Process row
        string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
        myData.Add(new MyStruct()
        {
            NS = fields[0],
            Sek = fields[1],
            Radial = fields[2]
        });            
    }
```

now you will have the list of your data objects;
You can do it in many way, but I would do it like this:
creating your own control like subwindow, in that control you will have one grid where you will create rows and columns as you want and placing there your button/checkbox etc. with your params, or of course create just some grid on your window and making it in window.cs

Comment: The OP doesn't **have** to use the `TextFieldParser` class, but that is probably a better approach than trying to parse the CSV directly with `String.Split`.

Comment: Of course he isn't, but it would be a good way to do it if he will use only csv and no other formats like xsl, xml, json etc.